# Return a class object from a function

Tags: python, ruby, function

I am trying to do the following

```
def func():
    var = some_class()
    return var

def fun2():
    func.some_method_of_some_class
```

In ruby I can accomplish this by doing something like:

```
def func
  @var ||= someclass.new
end

def func2
  func.somemethodofclass
end
```

the error I get when I try to run the python bit is the following:

```
'function' object has no attribute
```

Comment: You need to actually call the function in order to execute it and obtain the returned class instance:  `func().some_method_of_some_class`

Comment: Could you give an example that better shows what you're trying to achieve? It's likely that there are alternative ways to implement this. Also, note that you can just `return some_class()` (or `return SomeClass()`, if you're following [PEP-0008](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

Comment: My functions within my module will basically use a db class instance to perform queries... the way I use the db class instance is by defining a function which returns the class object and use that function across my functions in the module, does that make sense? I opted for module rather than a class, which inits the db class etc... do you think it's bad practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python requires `()` when you call a function. That's the only thing you're missing.

```
def fun2():
    return func().some_method_of_some_class()
```